# Google Authenticator with PHP not working

Tags: sonata, authenticator

im trying to make use of the project https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator
I have first installed the project with: composer require sonata-project/google-authenticator .
after this when I want to see the action I receive an error

PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Sonata\GoogleAuthenticator\GoogleAuthenticatorInterface' not found in /home/######/vendor/sonata-project/google-authenticator/src/GoogleAuthenticator.php on line 19

Am I forgetting something ?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you solved this, or got around it somehow. But the answer for me was changing

```
include_once __DIR__.'/src/FixedBitNotation.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleAuthenticator.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleQrUrl.php';
```

```
include_once __DIR__.'/src/FixedBitNotation.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleAuthenticatorInterface.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleAuthenticator.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleQrUrl.php';
```

that is, adding: include_once __DIR__.'/src/GoogleAuthenticatorInterface.php';

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to ur GoogleAuthenticator.php file which is in src folder

```
include_once 'GoogleAuthenticatorInterface.php';
```